# ImportError cannot import name celery

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to add Celery on top my existing Flask app, I have shared my project file structure below. I do not have `__init__.py` file in my project.

I have task **run_job** in `jobs.py` , but fromm app.py I can not import celery object I created. But I am receiving below error. I believe I am getting error because of my project structure and not having init file. Is there way to over come this without using `__init__.py`

**ImportError: cannot import name 'celery'**

```
<pre>+ root/  
  - flask-app/  
    * app.py  
    * tasks.py
    * jobs.py
    * jobs_namespace.py</pre>
```

My app.py looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from tasks import make_celery

APP = Flask(__name__)
...
celery = make_celery(APP) # cannot import in jobs.py
```

My tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery
def make_celery(app):
...
```

My jobs.py

```
from app import celery
@celery.task()
def run_job():
...
```

MY jobs_namescape.py:

```
@api.route("/")
def home():
   result = jobs.run_job().apply_async(args=None, countdown=60)
```

Comment: in `app.py` you named a variable `celery` that might be causing the problem? Not sure.

Comment: @Poojan that variable stores `Celery` object I am trying to import that variable

Comment: Did you try renaming the variable celery? If that's not the issue, may be try adding current directory to path with sys.path.append("path/to/current/directory") in jobs.py, right before you import celery?

Answer (score 0):

You either `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/your/project/root:$PYTHONPATH` and then try again or modify the code to have `from .app import celery`. I humbly believe you picked a terrible name for that variable. `celery_app` or something similar that does not clash with Celery module with the same name would make much more sense.

Comment: I did update variable name and set PYTHONPATH but now getting `    from .app import celery_app
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
`

Comment: If you use PYTHONPATH, you do not need `from .app`, you use it regularly (`from app`)

Comment: At that time I get `ImportError: cannot import name celery_app`  In `app.py` when I look at the type of `celery_app` output is <class 'celery.app.base.Celery'>

Comment: Did you actually modify your app.py to use `celery_app` variable instead of `celery` ?

Comment: modify the `celery = Celery(` to `celery_app = Celery(` and use that reference around... The problem you have has nothing to do with Celery - this is a typical Python problem with imports, and messed names...